# Salesforce weekly data export and GDPR compliance

Tags: data, document, gdpr

Many customers leverage the [Weekly Data Export](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_exportdata.htm&type=5) function to download Salesforce data.

How can one still leverage this function while being GDPR compliant?

Would uploading the zip folder to Salesforce Documents suffice (i.e. - don't store this data locally)? Or would additional steps need to be made, such as password protect the files, only grant Salesforce file access to a subset of users etc?

I know that there are many backup Salesforce vendors (Spanning, OwnBackup, Odaseva) but those solutions may be 'overkill' for a subset of Salesforce customers who, relatively speaking, have a small amount of data.

Having gone through several [Salesforce videos](http://www.salesforcesummaries.com/2018-01-26-Enable-Your-Customers-to-Blaze-a-Trail-to-GDPR-Readiness/) and documents on GDPR, I don't see any explicit reference to how to get the benefits of the Weekly Data Export function while still being GDPR compliant.